# why jstack out says thread state is "RUNNABLE" while socketRead

Tags: java

I have following stacktrace, the thread is blocking at socket read,
why its state is "RUNNABLE" instead of "BLOCKED" ?

```
    "Thread-80" daemon cpu=390.00 [reset 390.00] ms elapsed=6724.68 [reset 6724.68] s allocated=8140992 B (7.76 MB) [reset 8140992 B (7.76 MB)] defined_classes=81
io= file i/o: 130069/0 B, net i/o: 314790/394506 B, files opened:0, socks opened:0  [reset file i/o: 130069/0 B, net i/o: 314790/394506 B, files opened:0, socks opened:0 ] 
prio=6 tid=0x000000002bbeb000 nid=0x35f4 / 13812 runnable  [_thread_in_native (_at_safepoint), stack(0x0000000032630000,0x00000000326a0000)] [0x000000003269e000]
"Thread-80" daemon cpu=390.00 [reset 390.00] ms elapsed=6724.68 [reset 6724.68] s allocated=8140992 B (7.76 MB) [reset 8140992 B (7.76 MB)] defined_classes=81
io= file i/o: 130069/0 B, net i/o: 314790/394506 B, files opened:0, socks opened:0  [reset file i/o: 130069/0 B, net i/o: 314790/394506 B, files opened:0, socks opened:0 ] 
prio=6 tid=0x000000002bbeb000 nid=0x35f4 / 13812 runnable  [_thread_in_native (_at_safepoint), stack(0x0000000032630000,0x00000000326a0000)] [0x000000003269e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;[BIII)I(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read([BIII)I(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    - additional info (remote: default/127.0.0.1:56462, local: localhost/127.0.0.1:2001)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read([BII)I(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    - additional info (remote: default/127.0.0.1:56462, local: localhost/127.0.0.1:2001)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Ljava/io/InputStream;[BII)I(InputRecord.java:442)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/io/OutputStream;)V(InputRecord.java:480)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Lsun/security/ssl/InputRecord;Z)V(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
```

Answer (score 7):

Because that's what it should be.

`Thread.State.BLOCKED` means the thread is waiting for a monitor lock. It doesn't have anything to do with blocking I/O on a socket.

From the [Javadoc for Thread.State](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html):

> public static final Thread.State BLOCKED
>
> Thread state for a thread blocked waiting for a monitor lock. A thread in the blocked state is waiting for a monitor lock to enter a synchronized block/method or reenter a synchronized block/method after calling Object.wait.

`Thread.State.RUNNABLE`, on the other hand, means that it's executing (but could be waiting on I/O):

> public static final Thread.State RUNNABLE
>
> Thread state for a runnable thread. A thread in the runnable state is executing in the Java virtual machine but it may be waiting for other resources from the operating system such as processor.

Comment: So does it mean if a thread is waiting for IO, it is still in RUNABLE State and still takes the cpu? Are there any ways to release the cpu when waiting for IO?